# How can i update key in nested Python dictionary with a value from a variable?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key

this is a sample nested dictionary in *JSON* format.

```
{
    "dict1": {
        "key": "value",
    },
    "dict2": {
        "dict_id": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to replace "*dict_id*" with a string derived from a variable which generates IDs in Numbers. example "1001", "1002", "1003" so it gives me following output.

```
{
        "dict1": {
            "key": "value",
        },
        "dict2": {
            "1001": {
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": "value2",
            },
             "1002": {
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": "value2",
            },
              "1003": {
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": "value2",
            }
        }
    }
```

how can i get the above results?, any help will be appreciated. thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [dictionary comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/dict_comprehension.html) should work here to restructure the dictionary:

```
d = {
    "dict1": {
        "key": "value",
    },
    "dict2": {
        "dict_id": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
         }
    }
}

ids = ["1001", "1002", "1003"]

result = {"dict1": d["dict1"], "dict2": {i: d["dict2"]["dict_id"] for i in ids}}

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'dict1': {'key': 'value'}, 'dict2': {'1001': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, '1002': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, '1003': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}}}
```